# Algorithm to find multiple rectangles in an irregular polygon

Tags: c#, algorithm, coordinates, line, breadth-first-search

I have an irregular polygon made from multiple lines, as seen below:

[image]

I'm trying to find the multiple different large rectangles that can be seen in this polygon, as seen in the image below:

[image]

I cannot find an algorithm that will give me this result (or anything close). I've performed a modified version of BFS to determine the border/outline of the shape, but so far it has not helped a great deal.

I'm writing in C# (however any code that may help will be greatly appreciated).

Comment: At the top-left of the red rectangle, one of the rectangles sticks out a few pixels to the left of its column.  Why isn't that being counted as a separate horizontal line?  Is there some minimal size?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm not quite sure what you're asking. All of the lines of the polygon are separate lines, and I do not have control over how they appear unfortunately, but they will nearly always fit inside an obvious large rectangle, such as the red, green and pink ones shown. I hope that makes some sort of sense

Comment: I'm asking why the result isn't [this](https://imgur.com/a/xcd3r) (note the new yellow rectangle I added).

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, there should be a minimum size, my thinking it that the size should be able to be calculated (roughly) from the average length of line in the polygon @BradleyUffner

Comment: It is unclear whether you didn't draw the colored rectangles over the lines because the whole figure must be covered or just to avoid hiding them. Do you want a cover or just "some" large rectangles ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see, all lines must be covered, yes - the rectangles were drawn slightly outside of the lines to show the rectangles I'm after

Comment: @JoeMorgan: this answer is contradicting itself, so I still don't know what you want. Try to understand what I don't understand. Maybe show an exact  solution.

Comment: I apologise. When I look at the first image I can see 3 distinct large rectangular shapes in the polygon, as depicted by the red, green and blue boxes in the second image (I've reuploaded the images showing the lines I believe make up each of the boxes).

Comment: Is this image also your input? Or are you getting a graph with nodes?

Comment: The input is a set of lines, so yes, a graph with nodes @Glubus

Comment: @JoeMorgan Alright that's nice at least. Does each node hold some information about it's location, or each line about its length? Does each node contain its connected nodes? If you do not have this information, there is no way you can do this without drawing each line and use some kind of graphical interpreter of lines. Generally for these type of questions, please add all information about the input that you have!

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific when I asked the question. Every line has a length, angle, start coordinate and end coordinate. Each node is connected to every other node. @Glubus

Comment: Surely not all nodes are connected to every other node? If that were so there would be diagonal lines everywhere.

Comment: @Glubus Sorry, every node is not _directly_ connected to every other node, but there is a path from every node to every other node

Comment: @Glubus: "Connected" means what Joe is saying: that every pair of distinct nodes has at least one *path* connecting them. The term you're thinking of is "complete"; in a complete graph every pair of distinct nodes has a distinct *edge* between them. A complete *subgraph* is a *clique*.

Answer (score 2):

I would always start with the simplest possible algorithm and see if it meets my performance budget.

There can't be more than a few hundred rectangles in this diagram, so enumerate *all* of them.  Put them in a set.

Now form the subset of rectangles in that set which are *not fully inside another rectangle in the original set*.

Now form the subset of that set which is rectangles of a certain minimum area / perimeter / whatever.

And you're done.  No messing about with searches and traversals and whatnot. You want to find the biggest things in a set? List all of them and throw away the small ones.

Even naive implementations of this sketch should be around O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the number of vertices, which seems to be quite small. You could do better by implementing some sort of interval tree collection but that sounds complicated and unnecessary; again, see if the simplest possible approach is in your performance budget, and if it is, don't optimize it.  Spend time on something else.

Comment: You're making some assumptions about the input here that OP hasn't confirmed. How do you know you can calculate the area of a cycle? Also *Now form the subset of rectangles in that set which are not fully inside another rectangle in the original set.* this seems like a pretty complex step, how would you do this?

Comment: @Glubus: If you cannot calculate the area of a rectangle then you have bigger problems.

Comment: I agree, hence why I asked OP if this was possible.

Comment: @Glubus: The algorithm for the "complex" step is would be `new HashSet<Rectangle>(rectangles.Where(r1=>!rectangles.Any(r2=>r1.Inside(r2))` in C#.  Implementing `Inside` is a trivial problem often given to interview candidates as an easy warmup question.

Comment: @Glubus: My presupposition is that the OP can find *a rectangle* and that the hard part is finding the *specific* rectangles they want. If the OP cannot even find a rectangle then that's the question they should be asking.